# Oracle SOA repository migration

Tags: oracle, repository, oracle-rac

Does anybody know whether it is possible to migrate Oracle SOA repository from a simple Oracle database to Oracle RAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. We were able to migrate from one database to Oracle RAC. We used RAC Scan address with a round robin method to toggle between 3 boxes.